# A problem about "neither.... nor"

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, spoken-english

I'm going to work and my 10-year-old son is staying alone at home until I come back.

So before leaving I say to him:

> **Do not** play video games **nor** eat ice cream.

Or,

> **Neither** play video games **nor** eat ice cream.

I have always used the **second structure** but today I heard the **first one** from someone.

Which one of the two is more natural and grammartical?

> **Note: I can simply say "no video games and no ice cream".**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is not correct, it should be "or", rather than "nor". "Do not do A or B or C, " for example, in a list.

The second example, though grammatically correct, is not *current* conversational usage. There is nothing *wrong* with it, but it's unlikely to be heard in conversation today. Certainly, it's a classical pattern, as in, "[Neither a borrower nor a lender be.](https://literarydevices.net/neither-a-borrower-nor-a-lender-be/)" It's good enough for the Bard of Avon, but not for the mobi generation.

Your third example *would* be heard commonly in conversation, but technically it's not a sentence. Where's the verb?

In general, think of "either... or" and "neither... nor" as binary operations. They apply to two things, or groups. For example,

> Neither you nor your friends can stay tonight.
>
> Either the Pistons or the Celtics can win.

Comment: So can I say : "Do not play video games or eat ice cream."  with the format: "Do not do A or B or C"?

Comment: Absolutely! That is correct.